# Android multiple items in a ListView

Tags: android, listview

So I want to create a counter app that has a layout similar like it is in the photo below.

I would like to have 3 items in each line and pressing "add new" should add a new line.

Should I use `ListView` or maybe `GridLayout`?

I know how to create a `ListView` with just a text in it, but have no idea how to do this.

Thanks.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Nedi.png

Comment: What research have you done to try to find out to make an adapter with more than just text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ListView` with custom `ArrayAdapter`. You can go through the example here [ListView](http://www.journaldev.com/10416/android-listview-with-custom-adapter-example-tutorial)

The best option is to use `RecyclerView`. Go to the documentation here [RecyclerView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html)
.

You can find tons of examples of using `RecyclerView` online. And from the layout of your image it looks like you need nested layout.

Answer (score 0):

You should use recyclerview for the same.
When you click add Button ::

```
        mAdapter.addItem();
        mRecycler.scrollToPosition(mAdapter.getItemCount() - 1);
```

Put this add method in Adapter. What Notify does is, tells the adapter that list has been updated which contains that data model, and so new view is created corresponding to that model.

```
public void addItem() {
```

> // this is a dummy object. mDetails is the list of items.

```
    ItemDetails item = new ItemDetails();
    item.setItem("");
    item.setPrice("");
    item.setQty("");
    mDetail.add(item);
    notifyItemInserted(mDetail.size() - 1);
}
```